# completely clean re-install of mysql on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, yum, mysql, rpm

I have encountered problems with a `mysql` installation on `CentOS 7`.  All the data is backed up, so **I just want to completely erase every remnant of `mysql` on the machine and then do a clean install.  My attempts have not yet succeeded.  Can someone show me how to do the clean re-install?**

Here is what I tried so far:

1.) When `systemctl status mysqld` reported `mysqld` was NOT installed, I tried `yum remove mysql`, but it told me there was nothing to install because `mysql` was already installed.

2.) I then tried `rpm -qa | grep mysql` and `rpm -qa | grep mysqld` before typing `rm -e $packagename` for each of the results

3.) I then followed the instructions in [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-5-6-from-official-yum-repositories), but when I got to `systemctl start mysqld`, the terminal "locked up" in the sense of just giving a flashing cursor on a new line that did not have a command prompt or any way to enter text.  Note that I typed `systemctl start mysqld` instead of `service mysqld start` because this is `CentOS 7` and not `CentOS 6`.

Note I also did `gedit /etc/sysconfig/selinux` and set `SELINUX=disabled`.  Now the `systemctl start mysqld` just results in a quick failure.  I want to do a completely clean install and start from scratch.

Comment: Does [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169900/setting-mysql-root-password-in-centos-7/170094) that I also answered help?  In fact it was you who I answered it for :)

Comment: @eyoung100 I took all those steps again just now.  After `mysql_secure_install`, it asked for the current root password.  I tried just hitting return.  I also tried the root password on the old installation, but each time I got the following error: `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)`.  I have been dealing with such a `mysql.sock` error for a whole day now.  I want to do the clean install to start from scratch so I do not see this error again.

Comment: I think the problem is deeper this time.

Comment: Try `sudo systemctl stop mysqld && sudo rm -v /var/lib/mysql.sock` then Follow the instructions to reset the root MySQL password, then restart `mysqld`  You can't modify, remove, or update a service while it's running.

Comment: `rm -v /var/lib/mysql.sock` gives `rm: cannot remove ‘/var/lib/mysql.sock’: No such file or directory`

Comment: `mysqladmin | grep l.sock` and `mysqladmin | grep d.sock` also did not produce any results.  I will repeat the steps to reset root password now.

Comment: No you need to remove the socket 1st, that mistake was my fault... `sudo rm -v /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`

Comment: @eyoung100 Thank you but there is no `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`

Comment: Good, since the service stopped, the socket closed !!!

Comment: @eyoung100 The one thing I can see that does not fit your instructions is that `ls -1 /etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community*` gives results before the re-install.  I just hesitate to delete the files listed as results without understanding how to do so properly. In any event, I keep getting `ERROR 2002` as shown in a prior comment above.

Comment: Follow Steps 1, 2, 6,7, and 8 in the answer you followed before after stopping the service

Comment: New error.  This time, in step 2, I chose `rm -vR /var/lib/mysql` to just delete the directory.  I then ran step 6, but then step 7 gave an error. `mysql_secure_installation` resulted in `ERROR: can't create .my.cnf.4862: No such file or directory at /bin/mysql_secure_installation line 105. Cleaning up... Warning: Could not unlink .my.cnf.4862: No such file or directory.  Warning: Could not unlink .mysql.4862: No such file or directory`

Comment: @eyoung100 Also, when I run `ls -1 /etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community*` immediately after steps 1 and 2, the result is a list of two repo files, so we are not completely deleting everything.

Comment: You don't want to delete those, as you still want the repo to download updates.  Recreate `/var/lib/mysql`

Comment: @eyoung100 I recreated `/var/lib/mysql`.  Should step 6 be `yum install mysql mysql-server` instead of `yum install mysql-server`?

Comment: No, stop and think... `mysql` is a dependency of `mysql-server`, so they will both get pulled in.

Comment: @eyoung100 After just now re-creating `/var/lib/mysql` and confirming it was empty, I then did steps 1 through 7 again, but when the resulting script asked me for the root password, it's reply to the root password was `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)`

Comment: @eyoung100 After `cd /var/lib/mysql`, typing `ls -al` at the resulting prompt gives: `total 12. drwxr-xr-x   2 mysql mysql   53 Dec 16 13:29 . drwxr-xr-x. 47 root  root  4096 Dec 16 13:22 .. -rw-r--r--   1 root  root  6140 Feb  6  2014 mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19525/discussion-between-eyoung100-and-codemed).

Comment: `cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf` gives `cat: /etc/mysql/my.cnf: No such file or directory`.  But for some reason, I cannot log into chat.

Comment: @eyoung100 I posted the results of `cat /etc/my.cnf` at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67058/private

Comment: @eyoung100 I do not know why stack overflow lets me in chat while unix.stackexchange does not let me in chat.  If you don't want to use the stack overflow chat room, I could try something else, like uploading to a file sharing site.

Comment: see this [tutorial](http://idroot.net/tutorials/completely-removing-mysql-server-centos/) `my.cnf` is not a file.