# Blocked by “E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) ”

Tags: dpkg

When I tried to install "php5-mysqlnd", my computer was blocked and the installation was blocked during the configuration, and now I have a lot of problems.

Here is my `dpkg -C` output:

```
The following packages have been unpacked but not yet configured.
They must be configured using dpkg --configure or the configure
menu option in dselect for them to work:
 php5-gd              GD module for php5
 php5-curl            CURL module for php5
 php5-fpm             server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI bi
 php5-mcrypt          MCrypt module for php5
 php5-cli             command-line interpreter for the php5 scripting language
 php5-mysql           MySQL module for php5

The following packages are only half configured, probably due to problems
configuring them the first time.  The configuration should be retried using
dpkg --configure <package> or the configure menu option in dselect:
 man-db               on-line manual pager
 php5-common          Common files for packages built from the php5 source
 phpmyadmin           MySQL web administration tool
 mysql-server-5.6     MySQL database server binaries and system database setup

The following packages are missing the list control file in the
database, they need to be reinstalled:
 phpmyadmin           MySQL web administration tool
 php5-mysql           MySQL module for php5

The following packages are missing the md5sums control file in the
database, they need to be reinstalled:
 phpmyadmin           MySQL web administration tool
 php5-mysql           MySQL module for php5
```

I can't remove php5-mysql, I can't install, I can't do nothing. I have this message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server-5.6 : Depends: mysql-server-core-5.6 (= 5.6.21-1~dotdeb.1) but it is not installed
```

I can't configure any package, I don't know what to do?

Comment: dotdeb is known for low quality packaging that break systems in this way. Try `apt-get install -f`.

Comment: See [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169900/setting-mysql-root-password-in-centos-7/170094#170094) regarding adding the proper repository. Replace the repoaitories with [these](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/).

Comment: Run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, [edit] your question with the results.

Comment: Also, `apt-cache policy mysql-server-5.6 mysql-server-core-5.6`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have re-installed my server using stable packages this time...